# How to fade between two 360 video background skyboxes in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I want to be able to switch between two Panoramic skyboxes with 360 video on them with an effect where one video fades into the other on command. How would I accomplish this?

I currently have my scene switching skyboxes with no fade in between. I dont know if I will be able to achieve the effect I am looking for without changing the current solution

```cs
public class VideoChange : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int vidindex;
    public Material[] skyboxes;
    public GameObject menu;
    public TextMeshPro debugText;

    void Start()
    {
        RenderSettings.skybox = skyboxes[vidindex];
        DynamicGI.UpdateEnvironment();
    }

    void Update()
    {


        if (OVRInput.GetDown(OVRInput.Button.One))
        {
            if(vidindex != skyboxes.Length -1)
            {
                vidindex++;
            }
            else
            {
                vidindex = 0;
            }
            RenderSettings.skybox = skyboxes[vidindex];
            DynamicGI.UpdateEnvironment();
            Debug.Log("h3er");
        }
        if (OVRInput.GetDown(OVRInput.Button.Two))
        {
            if (vidindex != 0)
            {
                vidindex--;
            }
            else
            {
                vidindex = skyboxes.Length - 1;
            }
            RenderSettings.skybox = skyboxes[vidindex];
            DynamicGI.UpdateEnvironment();
            Debug.Log("h3er");
        }

    }
```

Comment: You might be looking for e.g. [this crossfade shader](http://guidohenkel.com/2013/04/a-simple-cross-fade-shader-for-unity). Instead of storing a `Material[]` rather only strore the `Texture2D` or however you originally use the 360 video and crossfade on only one `Material` using that crossfade shader and script .. you might have to re-write the shader for the 360° though

Comment: was going to say the same, you'll need a crossfade shader